# Errors and issues in the RDS with MySQL 5.7 and Wordpress website

Tags: mysql, wordpress, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I have a medium website made in Wordpress with about 2,000 daily hits and 4000 posts.
The website run on EC2 instance m3.xlarge without any problems for over one year. But I constantly had problems with RDS MySql.

**My RDS instance is as follows:**

- Engine: MySQL 5.7.11
- Instance: db.m3.medium
- Type: Standard - Current
- Generation vCPU: 1
- vCPU Memory: 3.75 GiB
- EBS Optimized: no
- Network Performance: Moderate
- Storage Type: General Purpose (SSD)
- IOPS: disabled
- Storage: 100 GB
- Parameter groups: default
- Option groups: With Memcached

**Memcached configuration (default, I have no idea how to use these settings):**

- INNODB_API_BK_COMMIT_INTERVAL:    5
- ERROR_ON_MEMORY_EXHAUSTED:    0
- MAX_SIMULTANEOUS_CONNECTIONS: 1024
- CHUNK_SIZE_GROWTH_FACTOR: 1.25
- VERBOSITY:    v
- INNODB_API_DISABLE_ROWLOCK:   0
- BINDING_PROTOCOL: auto
- CHUNK_SIZE:   48
- INNODB_API_TRX_LEVEL: 0
- CAS_DISABLED: 0
- DAEMON_MEMCACHED_W_BATCH_SIZE:    1
- DAEMON_MEMCACHED_R_BATCH_SIZE:    1
- INNODB_API_ENABLE_MDL:    0
- BACKLOG_QUEUE_LIMIT:  1024

**The most common problems are:**

1) CPU RDS instance by 100% for several minutes hampering navigation on the website (apparently resolved after including the Memcached option);

2) Frequent log error messages are: "Aborted connection 698,774 to db: 'unconnected' user 'mydbuser' host: '+my computer ip+' (Got an error reading communication packets)" and "Warning Host name '+my provider hostname+ 'could not be resolved: Name or service not known "

3) Constant Wordpress error message while edit posts: "Connection lost. Saving has been disabled until you’re reconnected..."

4) Number of connections simultaneous has a limit of 296, but sometimes jumps from an average of 5 connections to 39 connections for serveral minutes 1 or 2 times a day, and drops the website.

The global settings that this instance has by default: http://pastebin.com/Ws1D5VDs

Comment: 4000 Posts are daily?

Comment: No. 2 or 3 posts daily...

Comment: We are getting the `Aborted connection` errors as well. Very frustrating and need to figure out a way to solve this problem.